# MediaWiki migration showing errors with old directory structure

Tags: cache, mediawiki

I recently migrated a server from an Ubuntu machine to a more appropriate and easier to maintain CentOS 6.5 VM.  After moving the software over and ensuring the paths are all corrected, or so I thought, I'm getting the below errors.  Any time it refreshes, it's attempting to pull file stats for files using the OLD directory structure of `/var/www` instead of the new `/var/www/html`.  Yes, I can just go and alter the directory structure and ignore the issue, but I want to handle this the correct way.

The new directory structure is `/var/www/html` and the old is `/var/www`.  The migration was done copying the entire MediaWiki directory structure and giving ownership to the `apache` user that CentOS 6.5 uses for `httpd` execution.  The database was copied by using `mysqldump` on the old server and then importing it again on the new server.  Everything appears to display properly, but I'd like to be able to fix this.

`[Mon Jun 02 07:52:04 2014] [error] [client 172.27.224.206] PHP Warning:  filemtime(): stat failed for /home/www/wiki/skins/common/images/feed-icon.png in /var/www/html/wiki/includes/resourceloader/ResourceLoaderFileModule.php on line 380, referer: http://172.20.9.10/wiki/index.php/Main_Page`

I am unable to determine where it is pulling the old filename from.  Thoughts?

Comment: The database, perhaps? `LocalSettings.php`?

Comment: LocalSettings.php doesn't have a hard coded path set.  I'll check the DB, but I'm FAIRLY certain it doesn't exist there.  I'll get back to you shortly with that.

Comment: Nothing I can see in the db (but it's a big DB).

Answer (score 0):

Those paths are cached by ResourceLoader. This information is most probably saved in the [module_deps table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Module_deps_table). You should remove the contents of this table if you change the directory layout